# How to modify the HTTP::Response after it has been written to

Tags: crystal-lang, kemal

I'm trying to write some tooling for Crystal (specifically Kemal) where I can see if the response content type is `text/html` and modify the response body thats has already been written to the `HTTP::Response` before it is sent to the client by injecting an HTML element into the existing html response body.

I've noticed that `HTTP::Server::Response` is write-only, but things like `Gzip::Writer` are able to modify the body.

How can I modify the `HTTP::Server::Response` html body before it is sent to the client?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but would `env.response.write("<div>test</div>".to_slice)` work? - [api link](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.21.1/HTTP/Server/Response.html#write%28slice%3ABytes%29-instance-method)

Comment: I just update the question. I want to modify the html content that has already been written to the html response body.

Answer (score 1):

It's written in Crystal, so let's just take a look at the source on how others do this.

Taking the [`CompressHandler`](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/src/http/server/handlers/compress_handler.cr) as an example, the basic idea is to replace the response's IO with something that allows the desired control:

```
context.response.output = Gzip::Writer.new(context.response.output, sync_close: true)
# ...
call_next(context)
```

So how can we make use of that to modify the response that's being written?

A naive (and slow) example would be to just keep hold of the original output and provide a `IO::Memory` instead:

```
client = context.response.output
io = IO::Memory.new
context.response.output = io

call_next(context)

body = io.to_s
new_body = inject_html(body)
client.print new_body
```

Of course that would only work when this handler comes before any handler that turns the response into non-plaintext (like the above `CompressHandler`).

A smarter solution would provide a custom IO implementation that just wraps the original IO, watching what's written to it and inject whatever it wants to inject at the right point. Examples of such wrapping IOs can be found at `IO::Delimited`, `IO::Sized` and `IO::MultieWriter` among others, the pattern is really common to prevent unnecessary allocations.

Comment: Had some fun with a PoC of the smarter solution, probably not bug free: https://gist.github.com/jhass/abf9a29c6309add414e2b852ac0fff69

Comment: With the second solution, you wouldn't know if the content type is set as HTML. Right?

Comment: Given the headers have to be written before the body, you probably could pass in and watch `context.headers` and toggle between a proxy and active mode based on that.